# How to port forward on firewalld to port listening on localhost?

Tags: linux-networking, firewalld

I would like to ask question regarding to forward-port rule for *firewalld*.

OS I am using is ,

```
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
```

## My Goal

Forward requests to httpd listening on 127.0.0.1:80

```
[root@development /]# netstat -atunp | grep httpd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2601/httpd
```

## Problem

I have set firewalld rule as below.

```
[root@development /]# firewall-cmd --list-all --zone=external
external (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0
  sources: 
  services: ssh
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports: 
  sourceports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 
    rule family="ipv4" forward-port port="8080" protocol="tcp" to-port="80"
```

However, if I send request from external host, firewalld *rejects* request to port 8080.

In this case,

192.168.11.2 (client) -------> 192.168.11.13 (8080)

```
[root@dellinspiron13z asset]# curl -XGET 192.168.11.13:8080
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.11.13 port 8080: Connection refused
```

If the process is running as **0.0.0.0:80** , it works perfectly.

Is there anyway to redirect requests to localhost port?

Answer (score 3):

This is how it is done:

`firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 nat OUTPUT 0 -p tcp -o lo --dport 8080 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 80`

Comment: Also see https://serverfault.com/a/1004742/253322 for an explanation

Answer (score 1):

You have to change route_localnet in sysctl on interface with address 92.168.11.13 or for 'all' if you lazy

In lucky coincidence I have fresh CentOS with same version, so by default this knob is disabled

```
[root@tesla ~]# cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core) 
[root@tesla ~]# sysctl -a | grep route_localnet
net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.route_localnet = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp0s5.route_localnet = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.route_localnet = 0
```

Comment: Didnt work. I think I am still missing something.