# firewall-cmd not allowing loopback redirect

Tags: iptables, redirect, firewalld

I am trying to redirect a port on the loopback interface, but it does not seem to be working

```
firewall-cmd --list-all-zones

trusted (active)
target: ACCEPT
interfaces: lo
...
rich rules:
    rule family="ipv4" source address="127.0.0.1" forward-port port="400" protocol="tcp" to-port="500"
```

but when I run `nc -v 127.0.0.1 400` I get connection refused. `nc -v 127.0.0.1 500` can connect fine.

Any advise for how to get this set up correctly?
Thanks

Comment: Given that port 500 works and 400 doesn't, can you confirm by running `netstat -antp` that some command is not already listening on port 400 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**firewalld** installs a rule in the `PREROUTING` chain of the `nat` table. This table is consulted only for foreign traffic.

Locally generated traffic traverses the `OUTPUT` chain of the `nat` table, so you need to install a rule with:

```
firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 nat OUTPUT 0 -s 127.0.0.1\
-p tcp --dport 400 -j REDIRECT --to-port 500
```